# cannot access variable from another PHP

Tags: php

I got a PHP named `data.php` and it looks like this:

```
<?php
   $my_color = 'red';
?>
```

And I wanna use its value for a CSS property. The main PHP named `style.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
   include 'data.php';
?>

.test {
   background-color: <?php echo $my_color; ?>;
}
```

But this is not working because if I inspect it in the network of the developer tool, the value is actually blank and looks like this: `background-color: ;`. Anything I do it wrongly?

**Edited**: After looking at the error log, it shows: `Undefined variable: my_color`. But the file `data.php` and `style.php` are in the same folder. For example, the folder name is called `plugin`, and both files are in this folder, no other folder and file there.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Are you sure though that these two files reside in the same folder on your server?

Comment: code should be working... because ı tried code and worked,please open the error

Comment: @maio290 Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @dılosürücü Any possibility causing this doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried enabling error reporting as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/4934937)?

Comment: Avoid relative paths and use absolute paths where possible for example use `include __DIRNAME.'/data.php';` (if the files are in the same folder)

Comment: @apokryfos why?

Comment: As others have said; you should be looking at your PHP Error logs. [**Read here about how to find and read the PHP Error logs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel) . You should be logging errors and not outputting them to the user screen for best practise.

Comment: Does `var_dump(getcwd())` actually output the proper path?

Comment: @vicipi4669 ok, so, are you showing us the code that actually populates that variable? If not please edit the code and show what's actually happening rather than a simplification. Cheers.

Comment: @maio290 accordingly to the update/edit the issue seems to not be the finding of the included file.

Comment: @Martin if  your root script is in a different path, and that script is what includes `style.php` then this code won't work. If you use absolute paths it ensures the file is referenced correctly.

Comment: @apokryfos I do not disagree that Best Practise absolute pathing should always be used, but in **this question** the pathing for the include is not an issue because the OP (in their edit) does not state any "file not found" error which PHP would throw if an include/require function referenced an unfound file.

Comment: @vicipi4669 make sure all erorr reporting is enabled check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) to make sure you see everything that is happening

Answer (score 0):

run it from terminal

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:1234 index.php //be carefull s should be uppercase
```

Click the link  http://0.0.0.0:1234 and,
visit the page terminal will show you the error

Comment: This is not an answer, as it doesn't solve the original issue. This could be a comment to guide the OP.

Comment: maybe... but  ı am sure that will show error

Comment: The best practice for this work is the log